# passing function returned value from a class to a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, function, class

i have a function inside a class called connecting.vb

```
Public Function bring_it(ByVal a As Integer) As String
some code in here .....
                Form3.Show()
                Form3.TextBox1.Text = dl.Item("workorder").ToString
                Form3.TextBox2.Text = dl.Item("ptw").ToString

end function
```

in form3  when it loads  i want the textboxes to have passed values

```
    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 dim al as new connecting 
al.bring_it(a) 
end sub
```

i had to use form3.show() in bring_it function because  when form3 loads it doesn't show passed values  but the problem is  i get two windows one has desired values and the other one is empty

i need to show form3 when i press a button (form3 is an edit window with textboxes )

i also think to change bring_it function to output an array but i don't know how to do it ... i don't know how to use that output array let's suppose that the resulted array is this

```
st(3)={"hell","yes","no")
```

when i call that function
`al.bring_it(a)`  how to get for example  `st(1)` and `st(2)` ...etc separately ??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I really like Nico's answer and the explanation. I offer this just as an alternative and because I think Tuples are handy as a pants pocket.

```
Public Function bring_it(ByVal a As Integer) As (WorkOrder As String, PTW As String)
        Dim strWorkOrder As String = dl.Item("workorder").ToString
        Dim strPTW As String = dl.Item("ptw").ToString
        Return (strWorkOrder, strPTW)
End Function
```

Then call your function thusly...

```
Dim result = bring_it(x)
txtWorkOrder.Text = result.WorkOrder
txtPTW.Text = result.PTW
```

Comment: this is what i have  inside function bring_it
            While dl.Read
                strangs(0) = dl.Item("workorder").ToString
                strangs(1) = dl.Item("b").ToString
                strangs(2) = dl.Item("ptw").ToString
                strangs(3) = dl.Item("ink").ToString
                strangs(4) = dl.Item("zone").ToString
                strangs(5) = dl.Item("description").ToString
               end while

Comment: and it doesn't recognize any of the parameters i want to pass  when
i call it that way 
Dim result = bring_it(x)
txtWorkOrder.Text = result.WorkOrder
txtPTW.Text = result.PTW

Comment: You need to reference .Net 4.7 to get Tuples to work. Do this in the Application properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the responsibilities of your classes. Your `Connecting` class is most likely responsible for maintaining a connection to something. This connection has nothing to do with UI, so this class should not have any UI code. However, it can provide some automatically determined parameters (this is what I assume the `workorder` and `ptw` to be) as [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-create-a-property), potentially read-only ones.

```
Class Connecting
    '...
    Public ReadOnly Property WorkOrder As String

    Public Function BringIt(ByVal a As Integer) As String
        '...
        _WorkOrder = dl.Item("workorder").ToString()
        '...
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, your form class (btw, please give it a reasonable name) can access these properties and assign them to its text boxes:

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dim al As New connecting 
    al.bring_it(a) 
    WorkOrderTextBox.Text = al.WorkOrder
    '...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options to return multiple values from a function.  Here's an example to return an array.

```
Public Function bring_it(ByVal a As Integer) As String()
some code in here .....
                Form3.Show()
                Form3.TextBox1.Text = dl.Item("workorder").ToString
                Form3.TextBox2.Text = dl.Item("ptw").ToString

    Return New String(){"a","b","c"}
end function
```

Calling it would look like:

```
Dim bringReturn() as String = bring_it(a)
```

And you can access bringReturn(0), bringReturn(1) and bringReturn(2).

Here's an example to return a tuple.

```
Public Function bring_it(ByVal a As Integer) As Tuple(Of String, String, String)
some code in here .....
                Form3.Show()
                Form3.TextBox1.Text = dl.Item("workorder").ToString
                Form3.TextBox2.Text = dl.Item("ptw").ToString

    Return New Tuple(Of String, String, String)("a", "b", "c")
end function
```

Calling it would look like:

```
Dim bringReturn as Tuple(Of String, String, String) = bring_it(a)
```

And you can access it via bringReturn.Item1, bringReturn.Item2 and bringReturn.Item3.

Nico's advice is good also but separate from my response.  You want to separate GUI from business stuff.